# WinForms Designer window in Visual Studio 2019 for .Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I am creating a WinForms application in `.Net Core 3.1` using Visual Studio 2019.

This is how my app looks like.

[image]

But on click form Form1.cs I don't see the designer window. While when I created the same using `.Net Framework v4.7.1`

I can see the designer window.

As per the below link, with visual studio 2019, I dont need any extra configuration/vsix to do so.

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-to-net-core-windows-forms-designer-in-visual-studio-16-5-preview-1/

This is how tools options window looks like

[image]

Don't see any such option to enable it.

***Please check & suggest how can I get the designer window & use the toolbar to design the WinForms app when using .Net Core 3.1***

Thanks!

Comment: I take it you've enabled the Designer functionality in VS Options? `Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and select the Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps option.`

Comment: You need to *enable* the Forms Designer. It's still a preview feature

Comment: @Adriani6 I don't any such option. Added the attchment of the same in the post

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please check the updated post & the above comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Kgn-web That would suggest you're not running the most up-to-date version of Visual Studio. That option is only available in version 16.5 Preview 1 or a later version

Comment: @Adriani6 It's been just **a day** that I downloaded & installed VS 2019 IDE

Comment: My solution was to add a second project to the solution. One with .net core 3 and one with .net framework 4.7.2. Both pointing to the same forms and classes. But don't know if it is a good solution, because on 4.7.2 you have infinite controls, on .net 3 I had only 20 controls on the toolbox and wasn't able to add more.

Comment: @Kgn-web Verify what version you're running. You only mention "Visual Studio 2019". It verifying that might narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Kgn-web you still need to enable the designer. I did so just yesterday. The checkbox should be third from the bottom. Did you install the *latest preview* or the latest RTM version ?

Answer (score 6):

Prior to Visual Studio 2019 16.5 Preview 1 you have to install the [.NET Core WinForms designer via a VSIX installer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/).

From Visual Studio 2019 16.5 Preview 1 onwards it is part of Visual Studio but [you need to enable it.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-to-net-core-windows-forms-designer-in-visual-studio-16-5-preview-1/)

Answer (score 2):

I addition to enabling winforms, keep in mind that not all .Net Framework controls are supported in .Net Core 3.1.. you can revert back to this links for more details.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59954655/6233944
- [Breaking changes in Windows Forms/Removed controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/winforms#removed-controls)

However here is a simple trick to enable all the missing controls:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037636/6233944