# Visual Studio 2019 C# desktop application .net core missing controls in the Toolbox

Tags: c#, .net-core, controls

I want to create a C# desktop application using .net core in visual studio 2019,
But what i noticed that there is only few controls in the Toolbox, 
My question is how to show all controls like: Datagridview, menuStrip...?

Comment: is this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037310/6527049?

Comment: Did you right-click and use the "Choose items" menu item?